# Issue with compiling a c project on Ubuntu 20.4 WSL

Tags: c, bash, gcc, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to compile a project using WSL bash on Windows (it compiles using cmd, but I want to test it using a bash terminal). I have three modules and these are the libraries I include in the project:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

The WSL still compiles a hello world program, but it could not compile my project as it gives the following error.

**The error:**

```sh
gcc line.o main.o textutil.o content.o  -o textutil
/usr/bin/ld: line.o:line.c:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: line.o:line.c:(.text+0xb3): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: line.o:line.c:(.text+0x123): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: line.o:line.c:(.text+0x417): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: line.o:line.c:(.text+0x444): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: line.o:line.c:(.text+0x471): more undefined references to `__imp__assert' follow
/usr/bin/ld: textutil.o:textutil.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `__mingw_vfprintf'
/usr/bin/ld: textutil.o:textutil.c:(.text+0x25d): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: textutil.o:textutil.c:(.text+0x318): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: textutil.o:textutil.c:(.text+0x45c): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: textutil.o:textutil.c:(.text+0x503): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: textutil.o:textutil.c:(.text+0x65c): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: textutil.o:textutil.c:(.text+0x703): more undefined references to `__imp___acrt_iob_func' follow
/usr/bin/ld: textutil.o:textutil.c:(.text+0x100b): undefined reference to `___chkstk_ms'
/usr/bin/ld: textutil.o:textutil.c:(.text+0x1079): undefined reference to `___chkstk_ms'
/usr/bin/ld: textutil.o:textutil.c:(.text+0x1196): undefined reference to `___chkstk_ms'
/usr/bin/ld: textutil.o:textutil.c:(.text+0x1520): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: textutil.o:textutil.c:(.text+0x15d4): undefined reference to `__imp___acrt_iob_func'
/usr/bin/ld: content.o:content.c:(.text+0xac): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: content.o:content.c:(.text+0xfa): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
/usr/bin/ld: content.o:content.c:(.text+0x16a): undefined reference to `__imp__assert'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:17: textutil] Error 1
```

this is the Makefile

```
CC     = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c11 -W -Wall -Werror -pedantic -Wfatal -errors
CFLAGS += -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 # we use strdup() and strndup() 
LIBS   =  # -lm

EXEC= textutil
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
MODULES = $(basename $(SOURCES))
OBJECTS = $(addsuffix .o , $(MODULES))

all: $(EXEC)
run: ./$(EXEC).exe

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo === LINKING $@ ===
    $(CC) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@

%.o : %.c
    @echo === COMPILING $@ ===
    $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -c

depend: $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
    @echo === COMPUTING $@ === 
    $(CC) -MM $(SOURCES) | tee $@

clean ::
    @echo === CLEANING ===
    rm -f *.o depend

-include depend
```

this is gcc version

```
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Probably have some .o files left over from compiling on Windows native. `make clean` and try again.

Comment: You don't have a single mention of CMake in your post. I removed the CMake tag.

Comment: If it's just the bash you want, there are Windows implementations, for example in Git. You don't need WSL.

Comment: Thank you, I restarted my laptop and removed `-Wfatal` because it gives `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option -Wfatal` and it worked. Maybe `make clean` does the equivalent of restarting. For git bash, it bugs sometimes and I needed to test with linux command.

Comment: Before restarting the laptop I installed mingw too as I had installed gcc only at the begining...